# Charging a battery without overloading the rest of the circuit

Tags: batteries, charge, 5v, 3.3v

I have a charger circuit (BMS) ***V1*** which charges my LiFePo4 ***V2*** battery, the battery also attaches to a circuit which can take a little more than 3.3v, however if for what ever reason the battery fails I don't want all the power from the changer shunted to the circuit.

Should/Can I insert a zener diode ***D1*** and clamp the voltage to 3.3v to avoid the charger destroying the circuit? Or should I add some logic which disconnects the circuit I want to protect when charging?

How would you do it otherwise?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpeUKS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Even if the load survives, both LiFePO4 and LiIon batteries will be destroyed by your "charging" circuit. The load will also be destroyed. LiIon voltage will rise to 4.2V, destroying the load , then higher, destroying the battery. LiFePO4 voltage will rise to 3.6V, MAYBE destroying the load, then when battery full will rise to 4.2V, destroying the load, then higher, destroying the battery. Solution: Tell us wat you want. Use a designed circuit.

Comment: https://www.powerstream.com/lithium-phosphate-charge-voltage.htm

Comment: "I have a charger circuit (BMS)" - Your circuit shows a 5V power supply, not a charger. Exactly what is your 'BMS'?

Comment: @BruceAbbottthis the above sketch is an example sketch in circuit lab, without the required resistors etc. I'm trying to get the idea rather than the specific application. I'm not going to order a BMS if I don't know whether the BMS will work for the application  have in mind.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I have a designed circuit which I'm trying to simplify. Voltage source will never reach over 3.7. I saw in a couple of video's reverse engineering actual circuits that something similar was done, so I'm trying to apply the same real life technique to my circuit as an experiment.

Comment: _"I'm not going to order a BMS if I don't know whether the BMS will work for the application have in mind"_ - good, because a BMS will not do what you want. The purpose of a BMS is to protect the cells from gross over-charge, over-discharge, and short circuits. It does **not** limit charging current to a safe level for the battery or for the Zener in your circuit.

Answer (score 3):

No, this won't work. For proper charging the battery voltage will probably be as high as 4.2V, which will damage your circuit. Even at lower voltages if the battery should fail as you imagine there would be a very large current flowing through the zener diode, so the diode would quickly fail and then your circuit would be destroyed.

You will almost certainly need some kind of dc-dc converter between the battery and its load.

Comment: I put LiPo and meant LiFePo4

Answer (score 1):

What Elliot says applies. 
As it stands the circuit will not meet your needs.

You need to tell us the Vin source, its current rating, battery chemistry (eg LiFePO4) and mAh capacity AND anything else useful what you know and we don't.
Why are you trying for a super simple circuit? Is cost of room or fun the driver?

Without the zener Vmax will be about Vin-Vf_1N4001 or about 4.4 V max at significant current. BUT as the battery charges and current drops Vf of the diode drops and the battery voltage can (and will) rise. Anything over 4.2V will soon destroy most LiIons.
LiFePO4 charge at the rate you'd expect for current in until they reach about 3.65V THEN they climb rapidly to around 4.2V - then they start to die.

WITH the zener the LiFePO4 battery will be far from fully charged (needing about 3.6V to fully charge) AND the zener will conduct whatever the power source can manage via D1. 
If Vin is current limited to no more than 1A D1 will probably survive.
Whether the battery tolerates Iin depends on its characteristics.
When the zener conducts the battery stops charging - well below fully charged.

Pzener = 3.3V+ x Iin.
Whether it dies, glows or just gets warm depends on ratings and Iin.

Tell us more and we can help much more.